# How to implement a follow sistem on django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-database

I am working on a django project and will like to impletment a following/follower sistem in it, currently I have a friend sistem which btw doesnt work at all but I will just like to have ideas of how I can write that code, the idea is to have a friend sistem like in instagram.

models.py file

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py file

```
    def profile(request, username=None):
        profile, created=Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        if username:
            post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
            user_posts = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner) 
        else:
            post_owner = request.user
            user_posts = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        args1 = {
            'post_owner': post_owner,
            'user_posts': user_posts,
        }
        return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

Comment: What do your models look like right now? Asking for ideas like this is to broad and Stack Overflow may close your question for not being focused. Add more details so we may help you.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte I will add that right now.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte if you want you can check my friend sistem on my last question that has more code like Friend model and its view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say to do the following to your model. Add `following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers', blank=True, null=True)` to it so one profile can follow another and be followed.

With this you can easily fetch both following profiles and followers of some profile. The `'self'` argument to `ManyToManyField` declares a recursive relationship and [`symmetrical=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) states that the reverse relationship is different, which means that if I follow you, you don't follow me.

To add (follow) another profile you can just do [`profile.following.add(another_profile)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add), and for removal (unfollow) you can do this [`profile.following.remove(another_profile)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove).

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

#### How to Follow

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(...)
another_profile = Profile.objects.get(...)
profile.following.add(another_profile)
```

#### How to Unfollow

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(...)
another_profile = Profile.objects.get(...)
profile.following.remove(another_profile)
```

Comment: So I dont need a new model for followers right? my profile view would stay the same?

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala It shouln't affect anything AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you! just one last thing, What should I add in order to make user also unfollow a user that is already being followed?

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala I've added to the answer some samples and links for adding and removing (follow and unfollow), check it out!

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala Don't forget to accept if it helped and solved your issue, also upvote perhaps. Glad I could help ;D If there's anything else, just ping.

Comment: really appreciate it;)

Comment: sorry I didnt undertood well the django docs, can you please explain to me how should I add "add and remove" to the models please? or can you put that on your answers code? I really need it

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala I've edited the answer with the code for follow and unfollow.

Comment: this answer gided me to achieve my goal which was have a follow system on django

Comment: Hi. I understood the code above but how can I get followers of `another_profile` or in general followers of any profile? I tried to add another many to many field as followers and use signals to add followers to `another_profile` but in unfollowing I had problems. e.g. if I remove a `Profile` from `following` from `this_profile` I couldn't remove `this_profile` from `follower` in `another_profile`

Comment: @amirhoseinarabhaji Well I believe that's already answered, all you have to do is use the [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) from `related_name='followers'`.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte When trying to add followers after creating users and profile object, I am getting this error  `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table Interact_profile_follows has no column named from_profile_id`